# python iterate yaml with lookup

Tags: python, yaml

I have this sample yaml,

```
data:
  - name: data1
    sourceType: aws
    sourceSpecifier: acme/data123.zip
  - name: data2
    sourceType: aws
    sourceSpecifier: acme/data234.zip
  - name: data3
    sourceType: webdav
    sourceSpecifier: acme/data334.zip
sources:
  - type: aws
    baseUrl: example.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
  - type: webdav
    baseUrl: https://internal-acme.example.com/
```

Please help to share the python script that will give an output:

- if data1, source url will be `example.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/acme/data123.zip`
- if data3, source url will be `https://internal-acme.example.com/acme/data334.zip`

Comment: THis answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46957067/python-parsing-yaml-file-and-printing-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310934/python-iterate-yaml-and-filter-result/75311082#75311082 helps!

Comment: You write "please help to share the python script", but SO is not a place to promote some script by sharing. It is a Q&A site where you post a non-working solution (so it should almost always include some code) and then ask a question about it (e.g.: why do I get X as result instead of Y?). Invariable you'll need an actual  question, as in a sentence ending in `?`, to be part of your post.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is called `"homework1.yaml"`, then load the data using

```
import yaml

data = yaml.safe_loads("homework1.yaml")
```

`data` should be a dict containing the keys `"data"` and `"sources"`. Of these, `data["data"]` is a list containing three dictionaries, and `data["sources"]` is a list containing two dictionaries. All you have to do left is to match elements. Since you haven't specified in which type of data structure to save the match, that's all we can do for you.

Comment: "Since you haven't specified in which type of data structure to save the match, that's all we can do for you." -- out of this one yaml containing `"data"` and `"sources"`, depending on `sourceType` from `"data"`, we wanted to transform/construct the value in order to pass  the value to a variable, for instance, if "data1" , sourceType is "aws", retrieve the "baseUrl" and pass this `example.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/acme/data123.zip` to a variable.